# MySQL username / passwords viewable

Tags: php, mysql

Sometimes when installing a new product on our web server, I noticed that the install managers (usually a simple HTML / PHP interface) automatically fill in our MySQL details in the form for setting up the database. The user and password are correct, but I never entered them myself.

If the software can do it, couldn't a hacker possibly do the same? Do I need to take any additional preventive measures?

I have set the permissions so that no one except the designated users can execute those scripts, but it still left me wondering if it could be exploited somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your environment is possibly setting the `mysql.default_user` and `mysql.default_password`, which those install scripts may be looking at. Try running `phpinfo()` to determine the runtime configuration and see if these configuration options are set.

Look at the [PHP MySql Configuration Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php)

Whether you think *any* script having access to the MySql credentials is a risk depends on your environment. I'd probably err on the side of not having these options set, and not only because of the possible security implications.

Comment: Your browser will also remember form details including passwords

Answer (score 0):

Normally these "products" should ask you to delete the database install scripts as soon as you finish installing, so that no one else can execute the database install scripts in future.

Also, you would not create or use any script that lets someone upload a php or any other executable file on the server and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The username and password are not encrypted and readable yes. Scripts that have access to your database have access to this information.

An attacker would need to upload or execute a script on your webserver to do so. I don't know any way to encrypt the username / password for MySQL.

For this reason you should delete any install scripts after you do not need them anymore.